# Build LSTM model for one inupt and two outputs

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, lstm, lstm-stateful

I want to build a LSTM model with one input and two outputs.
My data is same as figure.
My model is as below.
But it only predict one output.
[image: Data set is here]

could you help me to design the model for two outputs? thanks

```
s1 = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1,1))
Xs = s1.fit_transform(train[['y1','y2','x']])

s2 = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1,1))
Ys = s2.fit_transform(train[['y1', 'y2']])

window = 70
X = []
Y = []
for i in range(window,len(Xs)):
    X.append(Xs[i-window:i,:])
    Y.append(Ys[i])

X, Y = np.array(X), np.array(Y)


model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True,input_shape=(X.shape[1],X.shape[2])))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units=50))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(units=1))
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error',metrics = ['MAE'])

es = EarlyStopping(monitor='loss',mode='min',verbose=1,patience=10)
history = model.fit(X, Y, epochs = 10, batch_size = 250, callbacks=[es], verbose=1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `output_shape` of the last layer of your model should match the shape of your Y-data.

Since you have 2 Y-data, you can change the last Dense layer to have 2 units:

> <s>model.add(Dense(units=1))</s>

```
model.add(Dense(units=2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Functional API

For example:

```
input = Input(shape=(shape, ))

out1 = Dense(1,  activation='linear')(input)
out2 = Dense(1,  activation='linear')(input)
out3 = Dense(1,  activation='linear')(input)

model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=[out1,out2,out3])
```

Comment: Thanks Morteza. Do you know how to design the parallel LSTM?